# link_to controller action in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

inside my routes.rb I have resources: x 
but I also have another controller y, and in one of the pages I want to link to a 'new' action in controller x.

usually If I have a match statement defined in routers like

```
match 'signin', to: 'session#new'
```

I can go

```
<%= link_to "text", signin_path %>
```

but what do I do when I use resources as with controller x and need to link to the new action, without having to write match statements out in routes.rb

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'New', new_controller_name_path %>
```

And you can view all your routes by type `rake routes` in your app directory.

And if you want change default path you can write in **config/routes.rb** smth like this:

```
match 'controller_name/new', :to => 'controller_name#new', :as => 'only_my_new', :via => :get
```

And then create link:

```
 <%= link_to 'New', only_my_new_path %>
```

Comment: I tried: <%= link_to "test", new_x_path %> and it gave me the error: undefined local variable or method `new_x_path'

Comment: Never mind, rake routes really helped, I was using the plural of X rather then the singural. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  match '/signin' => 'session#new', :as => :new_session
```

now, your signin path is **new_session_path**

write in your view file

```
<%= link_to "SignIn", new_session_path %>
```

write in your terminal - $ **rake routes**

you can view your resources and other routes. for that choose your '/signin' path and write that path in your link.